# NGINX and AWS Login for Windows?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

I am asked to fix a problem on a AWS server. Here is the link: https://medium.com/@svsh227/error-413-request-entity-too-large-in-nginx-with-client-max-body-size-changes-in-nginx-6aacd525fe11

Fixing the error 413 itself is something I can figure out on my own. The main problem that I have is that the site is using Ubuntu to do this.

The problem is this: I have Windows, so the command line is different, so I cannot use said commands for Windows 10. Do I have to get a Ubuntu VMWare, or I can just use another software like Putty? Which one is easier?

Help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a Ubuntu app in the Microsoft store, it essentially lets you use the Linux terminal on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

putty will work just fine if what are you asking is 'how do i ssh into a ubuntu box  if I am running a windows 10 machine"